# Is there a way to pass down an Interface through props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to know if there's a way to pass down an interface through a prop.

for example, the component below tries to pass down an interface to the Apple component.

```
import Apple from "./";

Interface A {
  name: string;
}

const Component = () => {
  return (
     <Apple 
       ...
       type={A} <--- Pass it in like this
     />
   );
}
```

1- can the above be done?

2- if so, what's the type of the interface inside the Apple component?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You don't pass interface like that.. Modify your `Apple` component and set type of your `type` prop to interface A

Comment: All the above plus: React components are just functions so they _could_ have template parameters on their own (for example when you have `items: readonly T[]; onItemClicked: (item: T) => void`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass interface through props, as it only exists in build time, not run time. If you want to pass time somewhere you can use generics.

```
export interface AppleProps<T> { /* ... */ }

export function Apple<T>(props: AppleProps<T>) { /* ... */ }

// ...

import Apple from "./";

interface A {
  name: string;
}

const Component = () => {
  return (
     // You can provide generic arguments for react elements
     <Apple<A> />
   );
}
```