# Can we Use Generic Variable to Make an import with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dynamic, import

I searched a lot,for a solution to create a basic generic component.
For this i need to pass throught props an Array of Objects to a functionnal Component.

On this functionnal component i want to use dynamic values coming from Props like import MyDynamicName from "DynamicPath"

Example

```
import myComponentName from myPathVar
```

I want to use variables on an import line , this variables coming from _props . And i don't know how to solve this problem and if its possible

i tried this but didn't worked

```
const path = '../../examples/tagsProjectsa.json';
const abc = import(`${path}`).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

[but module can't be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krCOZ.png)

UPDATE :
TO Answer the question : No We can't do generic import atm so i trie to pass interfaces through props and this didn't worked too --> [Is there a way to pass down an Interface through props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714479/is-there-a-way-to-pass-down-an-interface-through-props)

So i use  type on my props to pass my generic objects. And it worked , i wasn't able to define generic types because can't pass interfaces to get types

Comment: The screenshot you linked shows `'../../exemples/tagsProjectsa.json'` ("exemples" instead of "examples"), is your import path wrong maybe?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Static import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statements cannot be used to resolve a dynamic specifier. From the linked documentation:

> Only single quoted and double quoted Strings are allowed.

However, you can resolve a dynamic specifier (e.g. a string held in a variable) using [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). This even works using [object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) as seen in the code snippet below:

> You appear to be attempting to import JSON data. Note that importing JSON data is not yet part of the spec, and that doing so requires using an [import assertion](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) which is currently only a stage 3 proposal.

```html
<script type="module">

const initialData = {message: 'hello world'};

const json = JSON.stringify(initialData);
const blob = new Blob([json], {type: 'application/json'});
const oUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const {default: importedData} = await import(oUrl, {assert: {type: 'json'}});

const result = importedData.message === initialData.message ? 'Success' : 'Fail';
console.log(result, {initialData, importedData});

// Cleanup object URL data after use
URL.revokeObjectURL(oUrl);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't use this but i change the optic and do the import on the un-generic module and then pass an object with data to my generic component